# Seabios and secure boot. Coreboot payload

Tags: bios, secure-boot

I'm choosing between Seabios and Tianocore as a coreboot payload.

Secure boot is a UEFI feature. I haven't found any mention of it in seabios documentation. It must be not supported.

Can anyone confirm it, please?

I guess since I want to use secure boot, I have to stick with Tianocore.

Comment: What is your actual goal?

Comment: @forest corebooting my laptop and using secure boot. I prefer bios to UEFI since most of them are a bloated and potentially vulnerable mess. But alas secure boot is not implemented in legacy bios.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely the case that SeaBIOS doesn't support Secure Boot because Secure Boot is specifically defined in the UEFI specification and a BIOS-based implementation without UEFI won't support it.  SeaBIOS specifically says it's a 16-bit BIOS implementation, and UEFI is never run in 16-bit mode.

It is the case that there are other trusted boot formats (e.g., Das U-Boot's verified boot) that are not Secure Boot, but as far as I'm aware that kind of feature isn't available in any plain BIOS implementation at all.  (Nobody wants to write crypto code for 16-bit x86.)  Note also that many modern operating systems simply won't boot with BIOS at all, so UEFI would be the safe bet here.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll read up on Das U-boot as an option. I prefer bios to UEFI since most of UEFIs are bloated, lack standardization, could be vulnerable and so on and so forth. Unfortunately secure boot is not supported in legacy bios so I may have to stick with Tianocore. As for the systems, I use only Linux and BSD's.

Answer (score -2):

Why do you think you need Secure Boot? This name is associated with an UEFI feature, and as you say "[UEFIs] are a bloated and potentially vulnerable mess" (I fully agree with you, and according to board status reports, about ~90% of coreboot'ers are using SeaBIOS - another sign that UEFIs aren't needed)

If you just need to boot more securely, maybe just use something like coreboot's vboot: it is a coreboot component which, if enabled, works regardless of your payload, be it SeaBIOS or something else.

Comment: Welcome to the community. Secure Boot is used for protecting the boot process, so there IS a purpose for this feature...